# How to extract DOM from URL with Jsoup after JavaScript has filled the page with elements?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the DOM from a website with Jsoup with

```
String url = ...;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

But when I print out `doc`, I get the source code of that website `(Ctrl + U)`. But I want to interact with the HTML code that you see when you use `Inspect (Ctrl + Shift + I)` on a website.

Comment: why dont your try 
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]"); all these things to fetch your data

Comment: @GauravRai1512 because the Document `Jsoup.connect` returns is the website's sourcecode. When you load connect to the website with your browser. The page will be filled with elements generated by some scripts, and I want to get the Document of the website **after** these scripts have added elements to the page.

Comment: Can you add a timer to wait?

Comment: Hi @GodsWithin , do you found a way to achieve it ? I'm currently looking for doing exactly the same